# Lucene term query not working properly

Tags: java, lucene

I am using lucene to index the edge structure in wikipedia. For eg. if there is a link from the page `"Albert_Einstein"` to `"Theoretical_physics"` with the link text being `"theoretical physicist"`, then I create a document representing the edge as follows,

```
doc.add(new StringField("src", "Albert_Einstein", Store.YES));
doc.add(new StringField("target", "Theoretical_physics", Store.YES));
doc.add(new StringField("edgeLabel", "theoretical physicist", Store.YES));
```

I create a index using the `Keyword analyser`, and make queries for incoming links to a `target_title` as follows,

```
public List<Document> searchTitleInLinks(String target_title) {
        List<Document> results = Lists.newArrayList();
    try {
        Query q = new TermQuery(new Term("target", target_title));
        for (ScoreDoc sc : searcher.search(q, 20).scoreDocs) {
            results.add(searcher.doc(sc.doc));
        }
    }
```

For query `"United_States"`, I should get all edges that have `"United_States"` as its target. But when I do the following,

```
        List<Document> docs = indexer.searchTitleInLinks("United_States");
        for(Document doc:docs)
        {
            System.out.println("TARGET "+doc.get("target"));
        }
```

I get inexplicable pages, for eg.

```
TARGET United_States (this is fine)
TARGET U.S._state
TARGET American_English
TARGET United_States
TARGET Non-profit_organization
TARGET Viscosity
TARGET Group_(periodic_table)
TARGET Ocean
TARGET U.S._foreign_policy
```

I know the term query is getting messed up somehow, but where? This is the simplest possible way of using term query as far as I know, but it still somehow returns bad results. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: What's `target_title`?

Comment: `"target_title"` is the title of the wikipedia page for which I want to get all incoming links.

Comment: I understand that. What is its value in this case?

Comment: in this case the value will be `"United_States"`

Comment: Not sure but I thought your requirement is to print "src" field of United_States target documents? not sure why you are doing System.out.println("TARGET "+doc.get("target")); Or sorry I didnt get your requirements clearly.

Comment: Also please do check your indexes using Luke to make sure your incoming data is bug free!

Comment: @Rushik all the results should have target as "United_States", but its not. Printing out target is just a sanity check,and from the output, its obvious that it fails.

Comment: Thought so, anyway did you validate documents in lucene index thru luke? luke will also show you field wise term count, that way you can find how many records are having this problem. Also are you sure your raw data doesnt have any problem?